# Characterization of Fréchet-Urysohn spaces using sequential continuity at a point

Tags: gn.general-topology, reference-request

A map $f \colon X \to Y$ is called *sequentially continuous at the point $a$* if for every sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to a$, we also have $f(x_n)\to f(a)$.
$$x_n\to a \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad f(x_n) \to f(a).$$
A map $f \colon X \to Y$ is called *sequentially continuous,* if it is sequentially continuous at each point of $X$.

---

In [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) sequential continuity and continuity are equivalent. In fact, this property characterizes sequential spaces in the sense that if this equivalence holds for every topological space $Y$ and for every map $X\to Y$, then $X$ is sequential. This characterization is mentioned also in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Equivalent_conditions). Although I am not able to find a reference for this fact in a textbook or an article at this moment. (I'd say this is well-known and it can be considered folklore.)

One possible way to see this: If $X$ is not sequential and $sX$ is the [sequential coreflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreflective_subcategory) of $X$, then $id_X \colon X \to sX$ is sequentially continuous but not continuous. By sequential coreflection $sX$ of $X$ I mean the topological space which has the same underlying set as $X$ but closed sets are only those sets, which are sequentially closed in the original topology.

A different argument: This can also be seen from the fact that a sequential space $X$ can be obtained as a quotient space of a topological sum, where summands correspond to convergent sequences in $X$. (See, for example, proof of Theorem 3.10 in [G].) A map from a quotient space is continuous if and only if the composition with the quotient map is continuous. Continuity of the composition map is precisely convergence of the image of corresponding sequence.

---

What I am interested in is the following characterization of [Fréchet-Urysohn spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space) (a.k.a. Fréchet spaces): A space $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn if and only if continuity at a point is equivalent to sequential continuity at a point. (Again, in the sense that this equivalence holds for each $x\in X$, any topological space $Y$ and for each map $f\colon X\to Y$.)

This characterization was not known to me until it came up in a discussion with my colleague recently. My main question is:

> - Do you happen to know about any reference for this characterization of Fréchet-Urysohn spaces?

But I'd be grateful for providing alternative proofs to the one I suggested below, too. (Although that was not the main reason for posting this question.)

---

I'll add sketch of the proof. I do not claim that this it the most direct proof, but for some reasons the remaining equivalent conditions were interesting for me, too.

> The following conditions are equivalent for a topological space $X$:
>   (a) $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn.
>   (b) $X$ is hereditary sequential (i.e., every subspace of $X$ is sequential).
>   (c) For each $a\in X$ the prime factor $X_a$ is Fréchet.
>   (d) For each $a\in X$ the prime factor $X_a$ is sequential.

If $a\in X$, then the *prime factor* $X_a$ of $X$ at $a$ is the space which has the same neighborhoods of $a$ as $X$ and all points other than $a$ are isolated. I have seen this terminology in several papers, see references in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71075/quotient-of-zero-dimensional-hausdorff-space/71408#71408). Thomas Andrews called it [local topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439471/topologies-coinciding-at-a-point-or-a-set/439481#439481) in one of his recent answers.

The important fact is that $f \colon X_a \to Y$ is continuous if and only $f \colon X\to Y$ is continuous at $a$.

*Sketch of a proof.* (a) $\Leftrightarrow$ (b): This is well-known, see [F, Proposition 7.2], [E, Exercise 2.4.6].

(a) $\Rightarrow$ (c): We want to show that if $a\in\overline V$ holds in $X_a$, then there is a sequence of points of $V$ which converges to $a$. But, since the neighborhoods of $a$ in $X_a$ and in $X$ are the same, $a\in\overline V$ holds in the space $X$, too. Since this space is Fréchet, there is a sequence of points of $V$ converging to $a$ in $X$. This sequence converges to $a$ in $X_a$, too.

(c) $\Rightarrow$ (d): Obvious.

(d) $\Rightarrow$ (b): We can use the observation that every space can be obtained as a quotient of the topological sum of all its prime factors. This shows that $X$ is sequential. If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and $a\in Y$ then we have a quotient map $X_a\to Y_a$ (simply by mapping points from $Y\setminus X$ to the point $a$). Using the same argument again, we get that $Y$ is sequential.

[E] R. Engelking, General Topology. Sigma Series in Pure Mathematics 6. Berlin: Heldermann, revised ed., 1989.
[F] S.P. Franklin, [Spaces in which sequences suffice II](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm61/fm6115.pdf), Fund. Math. 61 (1967); [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/214006).
[G] A. Goreham: *Sequential convergence in topological spaces*, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412558

Comment: "(a.k.a. Fréchet spaces)" Hmm, when I read Fréchet space, I think complete metrisable locally convex TVS. Those are of course Fréchet-Urysohn spaces too, but.

Comment: Well, Engelking uses the name Fréchet space. But I have included both names - so that people used to either of the two terminologies understand.

Comment: Sure, it's not the only occasion of the same name denoting different things. Just sayin'.

Comment: The question has been for almost two weeks and it has 5 upvotes and 129 views. I've decided to try to migrate this to MO, perhaps it might have a better chance of getting answer there.

Comment: If I remember properly, V.K.Maslyuchenko recently discovered the same charactertization of Frechet-Urysohn spaces.

Comment: BTW this post is now listed among references in French Wikipedia artcile [Espace séquentiel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_s%C3%A9quentiel) ([current revision](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Espace_séquentiel&oldid=141736024)).